# What is the correct name for the 4-space of special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, terminology

I refer to the 4-space commonly used to describe event-points $(x_0,...,x_3)$.  A massive particle traces out a time-like path  in such a space, since it cannot travel with a speed greater than or equal to c.   It the correct name for the space a Riemann space, a Lorentz space, a hyperbolic 4-space?  What is the accepted name for the space or manifold?  Do mathematicians and physicists ordinarily use the same name for it?

Comment: As Qmechanic reminded us, it is called "spacetime".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is called [Minkowski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space).

Answer (score 1):

What makes space-time Minkowski space is the Minkowski metric.
Mathematicians may have other names for it.

Comment: To avoid confusion, what is called a "metric" in this context is the [metric tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor), not the distance function of a [metric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space). In particular, neither Minkowski metric tensor, nor corresponding spacetime interval, is a metric in the latter sense.

Comment: One also should have $R^4$ (and not, say, $S^4$ or a punctured $R^4$ ( $R^4-P$ ) ).

Answer (score 0):

The $4d$ space of special relativity is called by physicists, Minkowski spacetime and by mathematicians, a Minkowski vector space with the indefinite metric being called the Minkowski inner product.

It is an example of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold because it carries a metric of indefinite signature. In particular, a Riemann manifold carries a positive definite signature. The signature here is $(1,3)$. This also means it is a Lorentz manifold. Since any pseudo-Riemannian of signature $(1,k)$ is called Lorentzian.

It's worth noting that what mathematicians call a Riemann surface is distinct from $2d$ Riemann manifolds. The former is actually a $2d$ conformal manifold, or equivalently, a $1d_\mathbb{C}$ complex manifold.

Comment: Surely, your reply is the epitome of elegance.  Regrettably, it conveys little to me.   Though I cannot blame my ignorance on you, you have done little to lessen it.   Still, thank you!

Comment: @geodelite: Which is the first sentence that you do not understand? Durely the first is easy enough: I said physicists call 4d spacetime, Minkowski space and mathematicisns, a Minkowski vector space. Is it the second or third sentence you falter on, or is it later?